# List ManyToMany related objects to the current user session

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-security, many-to-many

I have an existing database modeled the following way:

users - Id(PK), login, password

locales - Id(PK), descripcion, direccion, etc...

users_locales - user_id(K), local_id(K)

and entity classes as follow

**User**

```
@Entity
@Table(name="users")
public class User {

@Id
@GeneratedValue
private Integer id;

private String login;

private String password;


@ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinTable(name = "user_locales", joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "user_id") }, inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "local_id") })
private List<Local> userLocales = new ArrayList<Local>();
```

**Local**

```
@Entity  
@Table(name="locales")
public class Local {  

@Id  
@Column(name="id")
@GeneratedValue  
private Integer id;  
@Column(name="descripcion")
private String descripcion;  
@Column(name="direccion")
private String direccion;  


@ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinTable(name = "user_locales", joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "local_id") }, inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "user_id") })
private List<User> localesUser = new ArrayList<User>();
```

I need to use a option select in a jsp page that displays a list of "locals" partners the user logged in, but i cant deploy it correctly.

This is not fully developed and I'm doing one or more things wrong, because i can't fully understand how hibernate and Spring security works.

Would need to create a service in "UserService" that generated the list and this is what I need help.

I add some code snippets that I think could be needed for this task.

**userService**

```
public interface UserService {

public User getUser(String login);

}
```

**localServiceImpl**

```
 @Transactional
 public List<Local> listLocal() {

 return localDAO.listLocal();
 }

 //This just show a list of all Local objects in database
```

**localDAOImpl**

```
@Repository
public class LocalDAOImpl implements LocalDAO {
@Autowired
private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

public List<Local> listLocal() {
return sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createQuery("from Local")
.list();
}
```

}

**controller**

```
@RequestMapping(value="/index", method=RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView indexPage( Map<String, Object> map ) {
    map.put("localList", localService.listLocal());
    return new ModelAndView("home");
}

//Now its pointing to localService and this list all objets in database
```

**The home.jsp file**

```
<select label="Locales" array="Locales" name="Locales">
    <c:forEach items="${localList}" var="local">
        <option value="${local.localidad}">
            <c:out value="${local.descripcion}"/>
        </option>
    </c:forEach>
</select>
```

How could i do a list of "locales" related to the current user session? sorry for possible spelling or grammatical mistakes.

Comment: I am a bit confused, what is the exact problem that you are facing?

Comment: Thanks for your interest. The JSP just show all instances in table locales, but not the "locales" related to the user logged in.

Comment: Then please show us `localDAO.listLocal()` implementation.

Comment: Oups, my bad. I have edited the post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the moment you are selecting the whole table. You need to modify `localDAO.listLocal()` and pass the login as parameter then modify your query and use that parameter to limit the output records:

```
public List<Local> listLocal(String userLogin) {
    Query query = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession()
          .createQuery("select u.userLocales from User u where u.login = ?");
    query.setParameter(0, userLogin);
    return query.list();
}
```

Hibernate, Spring or whatever framework you use, don't limit data automatically. You need to take care of limiting retrieved data for current user yourself.

Comment: Thanks for your help but I have some doubt...How I can get the current user as a parameter in spring security? and which is the right place to do it? the controller or the DAO?

Comment: `How` entirely depends on your security framework. And `the best place` is controller as user's information is stored in session which is accessible in web layer.

Comment: I'm using `final String currentUser = principal.getName();` to get the  current user and passing it to the function listLocal you posted but i get this error: _org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.QueryParameterException: Position beyond number of declared ordinal parameters. Remember that ordinal parameters are 1-based! Position: 1_

Comment: Well yeaah it's working now!!! The error coming of something different than what is shown here, add back query.setParameter(0, userlogin), the correct value is zero. This is the correct answer to my question. Really thank you very much! ;)